# Faster and memory efficient distance calculation for large spatial datasets

Tags: r, geospatial

I am trying to match two datasets (lets call them dfa and dfb) using two criteria: distance and time. Both have the exact time and coordinates for when/where an event took place. I want to assign to dfa, the number of events from dfb which occurred within a) 2km and b) the 12 hours prior. Database dfa has 13 million observations and database dfb has 500k observations.

I have used two separate approaches: a) using matrices and b) a for loop. However, for the first approach I run out of memory and for the second approach it would take me >6 days. Is there a more efficient way to approach this task?

**Sample Datasets:**

```
require(chron)

dfa<-data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 13000000))
colnames(dfa)<-c('eventid','date','time','date_time','lat','long')
dfa$eventid<-1:nrow(dfa)
dfa$date<-as.Date(sample(as.Date("2015-01-01"):as.Date("2020-12-31"),2000, replace = T),origin = '1970-01-01')
dfa$time<-sample(0:23,2000,replace=T)
dfa$date_time<-chron(dates=as.numeric(dfa$date),
                      times=paste0(dfa$time,":00:00"),
                      format=c(dates="Y-M-D",times="h:m:s"))
dfa$lat<-sample(-4.5:1.5,2000,replace=T)
dfa$long<-sample(-90.5:-75.5,2000,replace=T)

dfb<-data.frame(matrix(ncol = 6, nrow = 500000))
colnames(dfb)<-c('eventid','date','time','date_time','lat','long')
dfb$eventid<-1:nrow(dfb)
dfb$date<-as.Date(sample(as.Date("2015-01-01"):as.Date("2020-12-31"), 2000, replace = T),origin = '1970-01-01')
dfb$time<-sample(0:23,2000,replace=T)
dfb$date_time<-chron(dates=as.numeric(dfb$date),
                     times=paste0(dfb$time,":00:00"),
                     format=c(dates="Y-M-D",times="h:m:s"))
dfb$lat<-sample(-4.5:1.5,2000,replace=T)
dfb$long<-sample(-90.5:-75.5,2000,replace=T)
```

**For loop option:**

```
require(spatialrisk)
data<-data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(dfa), nrow = 1))
colnames(data)<-names(dfa)
data$nbr<-NA
data$timediff<-NA
data$distance<-NA

nro<-0
for(i in 1:nrow(dfa)){
  nro<-nro+1
  temp<-as.data.frame(dfa[i,])
  buff<-points_in_circle(dfb, temp[,6], temp[,5], long, lat, radius= 2000)
  buff$timediff<-buff$date_time-temp$date_time
  buff<-subset(buff,buff$timediff>=0&buff$timediff<=0.5)
  if(nrow(buff)>0){
    temp$nbr<-nrow(buff)
    temp$timediff<-toString(buff$timediff)
    temp$distance<-toString(buff$distance)
  } else {
    temp$nbr<-0
    temp$timediff<-NA
    temp$distance<-NA
  }
  data<-rbind(data,temp)
  
  #Process:
  print(paste0(round(nro/nrow(dfa)*100,5),"% done!"))
}
```

Comment: There is probably not a simple solution.  Sounds like a divide and conquer strategy is needed here.  Can you break your original dataset down into yearly groups or smaller geographic areas and match the smaller groups.  Also do not used `rbind()` inside a loop, this is a slow operation and gets slower as the object grows.  Please do not provide the full dataset for sample data, if you don't want to run it, why would I?

Comment: Does your actual dataset have multiple events at the same time and place? `dfa` and `dfb` each have only 2K unique time/place values.

Comment: `buff$timediff<-buff$date_time-temp$date_time`? It looks like you are getting the events from `dfb` that occurred within the 12 hours *after* each event in `dfa`. It doesn't match with your description in the introduction.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @Dave2e that is the size of the data that I am working with. I am sharing an example, that is not my actual dataset.

Comment: Maybe using spatialite and its knn index is an option: https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=KNN2

Answer (score 0):

The approach described below is much faster, completing the calculations for the example dataset in less than a minute. The speedup is mainly due to only 2K unique location/time combinations in the data. Once the observations and events are summarized by location and time, the resulting tables are **much** smaller.

After summarizing `dfa` and `dfb` by location and time, the idea is to first, for each observation in `dfb`, identify the subsets of `dfa` that have the observation within their time windows. Then `points_in_circle` is called for each observation (in `dfb`) over only those events (in `dfa`) for which the observation is included in their time window.

```
library(data.table)

system.time({
  dfb <- setDT(dfb)[,.(nbr = .N), .(date_time, lat, long)]
  dfa <- setDT(dfa)[,.(eventid = .(eventid)), .(date_time, lat, long)]
  setkey(dfa, date_time)
  setkey(dfb, date_time)
  dfa[,`:=`(r = .I, nbr = 0L)]
  
  dfb[,date_time12 := date_time + 0.5][
    , c("r1", "r2") := dfa[
      dfa[dfb, .(date_time12 = date_time12, r1 = r), roll = -Inf, mult = "first"],
      .(r1 = r1, r2 = r), on = .(date_time = date_time12),
      roll = Inf, mult = "first"
    ]
  ][r1 <= r2][dfa$date_time[r1] >= date_time][,r := .I][
    , {
      i <- points_in_circle(dfa, long, lat, long, lat, radius = 2e3)$r
      dfa$nbr[i] <<- dfa$nbr[i] + nbr
      NULL
    }, by = r
  ]
  
  # "un-summarize" `dfa`
  dfa <- dfa[,r := NULL][
    ,lapply(.SD, \(x) if (is.list(x)) unlist(x) else rep(x, lengths(eventid)))
  ]
  
  setorder(dfa, eventid)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   27.22   11.39   35.19
```

Result (based on the example data generated with a seed of `2043422735`):

```
dfa
#>                     date_time  lat  long  eventid  nbr
#>        1: (19-08-20 01:00:00) -2.5 -79.5        1 1750
#>        2: (16-10-29 00:00:00)  1.5 -79.5        2 1500
#>        3: (16-07-18 15:00:00)  0.5 -77.5        3 1500
#>        4: (18-12-14 18:00:00)  0.5 -81.5        4 1000
#>        5: (20-08-04 11:00:00)  0.5 -79.5        5 1500
#>       ---                                             
#> 12999996: (16-09-16 23:00:00) -1.5 -85.5 12999996 1000
#> 12999997: (16-04-03 06:00:00) -0.5 -83.5 12999997 1750
#> 12999998: (17-06-12 16:00:00)  1.5 -88.5 12999998 2000
#> 12999999: (19-11-17 12:00:00) -1.5 -79.5 12999999 1750
#> 13000000: (16-08-26 16:00:00) -2.5 -88.5 13000000 2250
```

Comment: Hi @jblood94. Thanks for the reply. The actual dataset that I am working with has unique time-location combinations. So this approach is not feasible with the actual datasets.

Comment: You are mistaken. It will still work. And it will be much faster than your current approach. It just won't be nearly as fast as with the example data.